# iPhone colour display issue on iPhone 6 (non retina) vs iPhone 11(Retina display)

Tags: swift, iphone, colors, retina-display

I am setting colour from Xcode colour picker , it is displaying exactly as I want , but when I test this on iPhone 11 or iPhone 12 . Colour looks a bit different [image: iPhone 6 result]

[image: iPhone 11 result]

iPhone 6 display

iPhone 11 display

Comment: All dispaly settings are equal? Brightness, True Tone, etc. ?

Comment: yes all settings are equal .